# Custom square brush defaults to circular?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush

I recently learned to create custom brushes by selecting an area and using the "custom brush by selection" option.

What I'm trying to do is make a square brush with a slight tilt to it (I'm using transform to rotate a perfect square to a small degree). Every time I highlight the angled square and create the custom brush it gives me a circular brush that seems to be the exact same as the default Hard brush.

Has anyone experienced this issue or know how to work around it? Is creating a square brush impossible or do I need to build something more rectangular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a straight square brush. Then in the Brush Panel, rotate the brush how you want it.

[image: Rotate Brush]

You can do this, then save a Brush Preset which will remember the angle. So, with one straight square brush, you could create 90 different presets based purely on the angle of the square.

**90 presets because opposing angle would all look the same. 360/4 = angles which appear different than others (90)*

Comment: this in really great